# How I can implement firebase dynamic links in my unity game to trace the installation path?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to trace that when user click the cross promotion and go to google play store and then i want to verify that user install the game or not.I have attached the code that not working according to my points please review the code or suggest me any other solution that cover my points and update my console here [firebase dynamic link console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF9Pw.png)

I have the following scenario :

1. I have a cross promotion button in the game.When the "cross promotion" button in the game is clicked, a deep link with referral data is created and a short URL is obtained for it and update the “Clicks” in firebase dynamic links console.
2. When the app is installed from google play store after installation via the deep link, the "App Installs" count for the cross-promotion link is incremented and an analytics event is logged to indicate that the app is install after installation via a cross-promotion link and update the “App Installs” in firebase dynamic links console.
3. When the app is opened after clicking on the deep link but not installing the app, the "Re-opens" count for the cross-promotion link is incremented and update the “Re-Opens” in firebase dynamics links console.

```
 public void OnCrossPromotionButtonClicked()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Start());
        Application.OpenURL(deepLink);
        StartActivity();
    }
    private I Enumerator Start()
    {
       
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Set up the deep link parameters
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("utm_source", "google");
        parameters.Add("utm_medium", "cpc");
        parameters.Add("utm_campaign", "cross_promo_sale");

        // Construct the deep link URL
        deepLink = DOMAIN_URI_PREFIX + "/?" + UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL(APP_URI + "?" + BuildQueryString(parameters));

        // Log the deep link for debugging purposes
        Debug.Log("Deep Link: " + deepLink);
    }
    public void OpenLink(string packageName)
    {
        Application.OpenURL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName);
    }
    private string BuildQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var keyValuePairs = new List<string>();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            keyValuePairs.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
        }

        return string.Join("&", keyValuePairs.ToArray());
    }
   

    public void StartActivity()
    {

      
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

            if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
            {
                AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                AndroidJavaObject packageManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
                string packageName = Application.identifier;
                AndroidJavaObject packageInfo = null;
                try
                {
                    packageInfo = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageInfo", packageName, 0);
                }
                catch (AndroidJavaException e)
                {
                    Debug.LogError($"Failed to get package info with error: {e.Message}");
                    return;
                }

                string installerPackageName = packageInfo.Call<string>("getInstallerPackageName");
                if (installerPackageName != null && installerPackageName.Equals("com.android.vending"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Installed from Google Play Store");
                    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("install", "source", "google_play_store");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Not installed from Google Play Store");
                    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("install", "source", "unknown");
                }
            }
        
    }
```